# Capture Output of Python script in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, python

I have a script that monitors game servers. It is written in bash. However I am attempting to put together an advanced monitor to pick up if the server has locked up. This requires a small python script to query the server and it returns either OK, ERROR 1 or ERROR 2. What is the best way to capture the output? Currently with the script the variable is empty. I can confirm the script is running OK and returning a message.

```
if [ -f serverquery.py ];then
    echo -e "[\e[0;36m INFO\e[0;39m ] Running advanced monitoring serverquery.py"
    echo -e "$( date '+%b %d %H:%M:%S') ${servicename}: Running advanced monitoring serverquery.py" >> ${logfile}
    serverquery=`./serverquery.py 127.0.0.1 27015`
    if [ "${serverquery}" = "ERROR 1" ];then
        echo -e "[\e[0;31m FAIL\e[0;39m ] ${servicename}: serverquery.py Monitor detected ${servername} has crashed!"
        echo -e "$( date '+%b %d %H:%M:%S') ${servicename}: serverquery.py Monitor detected ${servername} has crashed!" >> ${logfile}
        fn_restartserver
    elif [ "${serverquery}" = "ERROR 2" ];then
        echo -e "[\e[0;31m FAIL\e[0;39m ] ${servicename}: serverquery.py Monitor detected ${servername} has crashed!"
        echo -e "$( date '+%b %d %H:%M:%S') ${servicename}: serverquery.py Monitor detected ${servername} has crashed!" >> ${logfile}
        fn_restartserver
    fi
fi
```

Thank you

Comment: You are missing a `fi`, but that might just be a copy&paste error. Otherwise is `serverquery.py` executabel? And is the python script printing to STDOUT or STDERR?

Comment: To color text in your script see  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/037?highlight=%28color%29  When it comes to test if a file exists use  `if [[ -f serverquery.py ]]; then ... ; fi`  When it comes to string comparison use  `if [[ "${serverquery}" == "ERROR 1" ]]; then ... ; fi`

Comment: Yeah copy&paste error :). serverquery.py is an executable that when run will return OK or ERROR.

Comment: Rather than repeating code, use a compound conditional: `if [[ "${serverquery}" = "ERROR 1" || "${serverquery}" = "ERROR 2" ]]` (or you could use a `case` statement with compound conditions for some of the cases).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

added 2>&1 to the end and it is now working

e.g

`serverquery=$(./serverquery.py 127.0.0.1 27015 2>&1)`

Comment: The ./serverquery.py does not really make sense. You should put serverquery in your PATH and use it as in `serverquery=$(serverquery IP port 2>&1)`  This is much safer for the fact that you don't have to bother about relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to edit serverquery.py, I would change the exit value for the error conditions and then simply check the value of `$?` after running it. If not, try changing your if conditional on output check to the format suggested by val0x00ff: `if [[ "${serverquery}" == "ERROR 1" ]]; then ... fi`.

Comment: The issue I appear to be getting is that when I echo ${serverquery} it is blank

Comment: Is `serversquery.py` printing to STDOUT or STDERR?

Comment: @dgibbs See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002  why ${serverquery} is returning blank.

Comment: added 2>&1 and it is now working e.g serverquery=`./serverquery.py 127.0.0.1 27015 2>&1`

Comment: So it was printing to STDERR.